# How to find symlinks in a directory that points to another

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash script that finds and lists symlinks from one directory (lets say some "Directory1") but only the ones pointing to files in certain another directory (lets say "Directory2"). I can`t use "find".

I have tried something like this but it's apparently wrong:

```
 if [[ -d $1 ]]&&[[ -d $2 ]]
then
    current_dir='pwd'
    cd $1
    do
    for plik in *
        if[[-L $file] && ["$(readlink -- "$file")" = "$2"] ]
        then
            #ls -la | grep ^l
            echo "$(basename "$file")"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: spaces after `[` and before `]` are important however `[[` is also a keyword in bash and slightly different from `[` posix sh, for example variable expansion is not split with `[[`

Comment: Why can't you use `find`?

Comment: @Dominique Because unfortunetly my teacher told so.

Comment: I was thinking about using dirname.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple ls with grep :

```
ls -l Directory1/ | grep "\->" | grep "Directory2"
```

Comment: Not exactly because it only compares the names and do not checks the path. I was thinking about using dirname.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
for file1 in $_cat1/* do
    if [ -L $file1]; then
        dir1="$(dirname `readlink -f $file1`)"
        dir2="$(dirname `readlink -f $_cat2`)"
        if [dir1 == dir2]
            echo $dir1
        fi
    fi
done
```